# Problem with 'grub-mkconfig' in Arch Linux installation: 'grub-mkconfig' fails to connect to lvmetad

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, lvm, udev

I've been having a problem with a reinstallation of [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) on a machine that's dual booted with Windows 10.

For various unrelated reasons, I decided to back up everything in my old Arch Linux installation and start fresh. I have the Arch Linux live media on a USB, so I went ahead and booted from it (in [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)), formatted my Linux partition and went through the Arch Linux installation guide.

Everything seemed to be working fine until I got to the 'install bootoloader' section. I wasn't 100% sure what to do here, as the beginner's guide that I used before has been deleted in favor of the (much, much more brief) installation guide.

I know that my [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) partition already had all the GRUB stuff it needed, but I figured it would need to be changed for a new installation.

- I deleted the `/boot/EFI/grub.efi` stub, and renamed `/boot/grub/` to `/boot/grub.bak`.
- I ran

  ```
  pacman -S grub os-prober
  ```

  ran the `grub-install` command from the arch installation guide with `target=x86_64-efi` and `directory=/boot` (my mount point for my EFI partition) and then ran

  ```
  grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```

This is where my trouble started. Running the `grub-mkconfig` command gave me a '`failed to connect to lvmetad`' error, and said it was reverting to fallback mode. It successfully produced a `grub.cfg` file in the correct directory, however there were no menu entries present.

When I try to boot, all I get is a GRUB command line. Going back into my Arch Linux live media and redoing the `arch-chroot`, I went into my `/boot/grub.bak` and copied the menu entry sections for Arch Linux from there, making sure to replace the old UUID with the one currently reported in my [`fstab`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) for my root directory. This brought the GRUB menu back when I rebooted, but selecting Arch Linux gave me an error that `/vmlinux couldn't be found`.

I went back into my `chroot` on the live media, and reran `grub-config`. Still no menu entries. I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105389/arch-grub-asking-for-run-lvm-lvmetad-socket-on-a-non-lvm-disk) with a similar issue that said there was a known problem with the `grub-mkconfig` helper script. This was from 2014, so I thought it was unlikely that my issue was the same, but I followed the best answer there. The suggestion was to do the following:

> ran across the same issue just now, and found another workaround. Basically, it involves making the hosts `/run` directory available to the guest.
>
> First, we mount `/run` where it can be accessed by the guest. I will assume that your install partition is mounted at `/mnt`.
>
> ```
> mkdir /mnt/hostrun
> mount --bind /run /mnt/hostrun
> ```
>
> Then, we `chroot` into the guest, and mount our host's `/run/lvm` in the guest's `/run`.
>
> ```
> arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash
> mkdir /run/lvm
> mount --bind /hostrun/lvm /run/lvm
> ```
>
> You can then run `grub-mkconfig` and `grub-install` without any LVM errors. This also makes the commands behave if you are installing
> with LVM, for what it's worth.
>
> When done, remember to umount `/run/lvm` before exiting the chroot.

Doing so actually got rid of my `fails to connect to lvmetad` error, but replaces it with a `/dev/sdx not initialized in UDEV`. The command still produces a `grub.cfg` without menu entries.

I'm able to get into Windows by selecting the Windows Boot Manager from my laptop's 'hammer <kbd>F12</kbd> while booting' menu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem appears only because you are in `arch-chroot` and using `os-prober`. What solved my case was:

- Backup current `grub.cfg`, if you haven't backed up yet.
- Remove `os-prober` (`pacman -R os-prober`, [or you can disable it](https://askubuntu.com/a/770390/800653))
- Run `grub-mkcondig`
- Reboot into Arch
- Install `os-prober`
- Run `grub-mkconfig` again

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. This is an old post but I will post my work-around in case it helps someone.

Like yourself, I had a complete backup, including a working `grub.cfg` file. I extracted the required menu entries from the old `grub.cfg` file and added them to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. Next I re-ran

```
grub mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

All is well now.

`os-prober` is a low priority convenience item and not really essential. Personally I would not spend much time trying to get it to work. It is a personal choice. Some people love trying to troubleshoot this kind of thing and I thank them for their efforts, but others need their systems for real work, have time constraints, and need to get up and running.

Eventually this problem will be fixed either through software or documentation. If you have questions about how to set up menu entries in the `40_custom` file, you will find numerous examples through a web search.